# jQuery Click Event Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that triggers (1) the application of a coupon code and (2) the submission of the entire form for payment.

The problem is that the coupon code is taking a couple of seconds to apply so is applying after the entire form is submitted for payment. How can I delay the click of the second payment button so that the coupon code button is applied first?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.js-coll-button2').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('#sc_checkout_form_1').find('.sc-coup-apply-btn').click();
  jQuery('#sc_checkout_form_1').find('.sc-payment-btn').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can make use a setTimeout(function(){},milliseconds)

Comment: Hi! Where would I include the setTimeout code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Second click
}, seconds * 1000);
```

Put your second click code in the `setTimeout` closure function

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong! It's not the right way to use these kind of services!

Answer (score 4):

That would be unwise. You have no guarantee that a certain amount of time will be always enough. It depends on the client's computer and connection, and what if the first action returns an error?

The best way to do this would be to fire the second function only if the first has completed.

**Edit:** I've never used Stripe from Javascript, but the API manual says clearly that every REST call returns a code.

And, you should not try to FORCE the clicks but use funcions instead. Decouple your functionality from the buttons!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doCoupon() {
     return $.ajax(... do your stripe call ...);
}

function doAnotherThing() {
    return $.ahax(... call your other thingie... );
}

function handleError() {
    // ... 
}

jQuery("#sc_checkout_form_1 .sc-coup-apply-btn").click(doCoupon);
jQuery("#sc_checkout_form_1 .sc-payment-btn").click(doAnotherThing);


jQuery('.js-coll-button2').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    doCoupon().success(doAnotherThing).error(handleError);  
});
</script>
```

Comment: That would be ideal. How would I do that?

Comment: Is the coupon code yours or is it an external service?

Comment: @pdawson90 Updated my code. And please DON'T use Yassine Housini 's method, it is a **bad practice**.

Comment: @pdawson90 I agree with Cranio, you should use his answer

Comment: Thanks @Cranio - I'm trying this solution but unsure what to put in the gaps after .ajax(). I also need to allow the payment button to submit if nothing is entered in the coupon field but not sure if this needs to be reflected in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a simple delay, I think jQuery can do this: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
jQuery('#sc_checkout_form_1').find('.sc-payment-btn').delay(1000).click();
```

Or use `setTimeout` as per other answers.

Just relying on a timeout / wait isn't a guarenteed solution however, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007018/15667